# Trying to add/change a class within a <td> tag based on condition when the <td> is part of a string

Tags: javascript, css, coffeescript

How would I change the class based on a condition when the  tag is part of a string in coffeeScript:

```
rows+= "<tr class='row'>" + 
         "<td class='name'>" + awayTeam + "</td>" +
         "<td class='score'>" + aScore + "</td>" +
         "<td class='name'>" + homeTeam + "</td>" +
         "<td class='score'>" + hScore + "</td>"  +
         "<td class='period'>" + currentPeriod + "</td>" +
       "</tr>"


table = "<table class='data'>" + rows + "</table>"

return table
```

If aScore > hScore, how can I change the class='name' to class='winning'?

I have tried....

```
"<td class="${(aScore>hScore) ? 'winning' : 'name'}">" + awayTeam + "</td>"
```

but get an unexpected identifier error.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expecting aScore and hScore as integers.
Then this should work,

```
var res_class = ( aScore > hScore ) ? 'winning' : 'name';

rows+= "<tr class='row'>" + 
         "<td class='"+res_class+"'>" + awayTeam + "</td>" +
         "<td class='score'>" + aScore + "</td>" +
         "<td class='name'>" + homeTeam + "</td>" +
         "<td class='score'>" + hScore + "</td>"  +
         "<td class='period'>" + currentPeriod + "</td>" +
       "</tr>";
table = "<table class='data'>" + rows + "</table>";

return table
```

Comment: @Woody ok...then please accept this answer. To help others in finding this as solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:
you must select `ascore` and `hscore` separately to compare values, so I change their class name to `score-ascore` and `score-hscore`.

after condition occurred change `name` class with `winning`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('body').html(create())
      var ascore = $('.score-ascore').text()
      var hscore = $('.score-hscore').text()
      if(aScore>hScore){
        var element = $("td.name")
        element.addClass("winning")
        element.removeClass("name")
      }

  })

  function create(){
    awayTeam = 10
    aScore = 10
    homeTeam = 10
    hScore = 9
    currentPeriod = 10
    rows = 10
    rows+= '<tr class="row">' + 
         '<td class="name">' + awayTeam + '</td>' +
         '<td class="score-ascore">' + aScore + '</td>' +
         '<td class="name">' + homeTeam + '</td>' +
         '<td class="score-hscore">' + hScore + '</td>'  +
         '<td class="period">' + currentPeriod + '</td>' +
       '</tr>'
      table = '<table class="data">' + rows + '</table>'
      return table
  }
</script>
</html>
```